# Passing Variables Between Forms

Tags: mysql, vb.net

Forgive me if this has already been asked- I can’t seem to find a well written answer.

I am developing a small application for personal use.

Essentially what I have is two forms. Form 1 is a master view of all my contacts listed on a data grid view. Form 2 will be loaded on the cell/row double click of a particular record in order to edit it’s details.

My question is, what is the best practice/method for achieving this? I have seen many different methods.

Should I:

1. Pass only the primary key of the selected row then populate the fields on form 2 load
2. Pass all fields as a variable within a class then populate form 2 from that

Maybe I’m headed in the complete wrong direction though.

I have tried both ways, but wondering what the best method is for scalability.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My personal preference would be to pass a `datarow` into the opening argument of the form (rather than the PK / all the variables). You can then use the `datarow` inside your `Form2` to bind to your controls or set their values, whichever you think is appropriate.

There are some useful [examples](https://www.dotnetperls.com/datarow-vbnet) on working with a `datarow` if you're unsure, alternatively you can also check out [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datarow?view=netframework-4.7.2).

```
Public Sub New(ByVal row As DataRow)
    InitializeComponent()

    ' your code for working with row here

End Sub
```

Edit:
In terms of "Binding" vs "Setting", you can either have your controls linked to your data to be two way (as you edit the data in a control at run time you alter the data in your database) or you can just set the values of the controls.

E.G. `TextBox1.Text = row(0)("ColumnName")`

You can find more on data binding on the [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/data-tools/bind-windows-forms-controls-to-data-in-visual-studio?view=vs-2019) page

Comment: Does this method work if I plan on only showing a few fields in the data grid view? I.e my dgv on form 1 only shows first name and last name but the edit form should show every column in the table. Also, what’s the difference between “binding your controls” and “setting their values”? Why would you use one over the other?

Comment: I don't see why it wouldn't, you could just retrieve the PK for the row in question & build the datarow using the PK & pass it through. Will update my answer to elaborate on binding / setting